# Add contact to Exchange from Signature

Tags: contacts, exchange

searched around a bit and found one app (Contact Adder) that didn't work.  What I'm wanting to do is add contacts to Exchange from their signatures on my phone.  Anyone know of an app?  I use Mac for work and nothing will do it in Mail.app or Outlook for Mac, thought I'd try on my phone.